# Verificar se tem a string e incluir suas tags

Tags: php

Gostaria de pegar o conteúdo do site, retirar só o texto e inserir minhas tags, porém neste código que fiz, quando ele acha o texto "Art" ele não sai do if, e então, só os primeiros ficam com a tag li, o resto todos ficam com a tag ul.

Alguém poderia me ajudar

```
    # Use the Curl extension to query Google and get back a page of results
    $url = "www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/constituicao/constituicaocompilado.htm";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    # Create a DOM parser object
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    # Parse the HTML from Google.
    # The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
    # loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);




    # Iterate over all the  tags
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('font') as $link) {

    $mystring = $link->nodeValue;
    $findme   = 'Art';
    $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

        if ($pos === false) {

            echo "li";
            echo $link->nodeValue;
            echo "/li";

        } else { 

            echo "/ul";
            echo "ul id='' class='artigo'";
            echo "li";
            echo $link->nodeValue;
            echo "/li";

        }
    }
```

para que o resultado final seja assim

```
    _ul id="titulo1" class="titulo">
        _h3>TÍTULO I_/h3>
        _p>Dos Princípios Fundamentais_/p>
    _/ul>
    _ul id="titulo1_artigo1" class="artigo">
        _li>
            _ul class="caput">
                _li>
                    Art. 1º A República ... tem como fundamentos:
                _/li>
            _/ul>
        _/li>
        _li>
            _ul class="incisos">
                 _li> I - a soberania;_/li>
                 _li> II - a cidadania_/li>
                 _li> III - o pluralismo político._/li>
            _/ul>
        _/li>
        _li>
            _ul class="paragrafos">
                _li>Parágrafo único. Todo o ... desta Constituição.
                _/li>
            _/ul>
        _/li>

    _/ul>
    _ul id="titulo1_artigo2" class="artigo">
        _li>
            _ul class="caput">
                _li>
                    Art. 2º São Poderes da União, independentes e harmônicos entre si, o Legislativo, o Executivo e o Judiciário.
                _/li>
            _/ul>
        _/li>   
    _/ul>
```

Comment: Para mim todos funcionou normalmente, até o final aparece `li.../li`, assim como aparece `ul id='' class='artigo'`

Comment: Para cada linha, ele deveria ver se tem a palavra artigo e aplicar o ul só nos artigos, mas ele aplica o ul na linhas que não tem a string "Art"

Comment: Mas isto ocorre por que o `ul` está no `else`, acho melhor você especificar como você quer exibir os dados, por exemplo você quer exibir o titulo e depois o conteudo do artigo? É isso?

Comment: Mas não seria este o uro correto, ele verifica se tem a palavra que procuro em cada $link, se a procura for falsa, ele vai inserir no $link, apenas a tag li, mas se encontrar a palavra ele excetua a parte do else e atribui só para os $link essa ul?

Comment: Não a parte do `else` é uma exceção, como existem várias tags `<font>` o loop pode apresentar qualquer coisa depois do if, diga-me exatamente o que você quer trazer, pois acredito que você possa usar melhor a API `DOMDocument` para facilitar o trabalho, só preciso entender o que REALMENTE você quer exibir e a ordem. Edite a pergunta para adicionar os dados.

Comment: A Constituição tem, capítulos, que tem seções, que tem artigos, que tem incisos etc, então pensei em envolvê-la numa nested ul (não sei o nome em português), então na programação verifica se é o titulo 4 e da o id de titulo4, se é o artigo 5, numa ul de id artigo5.

Comment: por exemplo 

coloquei um modelo do que imagino na pergunta original

Comment: Acho que deu para ter uma noção pelo seu exemplo, acredito que de para fazer tudo usando apenas `DOMDocument`, sem precisar `strpos`, como é algo demorado, amanhã de tarde eu tento postar uma resposta amigo, se ninguém tiver respondido.

Comment: Entendi, Guilherme.

Vlw man

Comment: Bom dia Ale, como pode ver forneci uma resposta e exemplo, se não tiver claro você pode perguntar, para tirar duvidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testando melhor o seu código, notei que o texto se repete algumas vezes, isto é pelo fato do uso do `getElementsByTagName` que pega o elemento pai e o elemento filho e o loop apresenta ambos com `nodeValue`, os textos sempre irão repetir. Pensei em usar o XPath, mas o problema todo ocorre por que este documento HTML especifico não possui divisão por bloco para cada conteúdo, ele simplesmente trabalha com quebra de linhas.

Talvez seja possivel usar o XPath ou algo semelhante, mas aparentemente é bem trabalhoso.

Então pensando nas quebras de linha, pensei o seguinte, ao invés de ler como DOM, você pode ler ele como texto, linha por linha e detectar aonde começa e termina o artigo.

Para fazer a leitura linha por linha recomendo usar `tmpfile()`, `foef()` e `fgets`. O `tmpfile()` servirá para armazenar a página que você está baixando.

```
//Gravar a página em um arquivo temporário
$handle = tmpfile();
fwrite($handle, $html);
fseek($handle, 0);

$html = NULL;

$initiate = false;
$inTitle = false;

//Função usada para remover elementos das linhas desnecessários
function removeTags($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = preg_replace('/[<][^>]+[>]|[<][^<>]+$|^[^<>]+[>]/', '', $data);
    return trim($data);
}

//No while iremos verificar linha a linha
while (false === feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle);//Lê a linha

    //Se a linha é vazio ignora e vai para a proxima linha
    if (trim($buffer) === '') {
        continue;
    }

    //Detecta aonde começa o artigo
    $findme = strpos($buffer, '>Art.') !== false;

    //Detecta um "possivel" termino do artigo ou titulo
    $endLine = stripos($buffer, '</p>') !== false;

    if ($findme) {

        //Se for já tiver ao menos um artigo adicionado ao corpo então isto detecta que terminou de listar os itens do artigo anterior
        if ($initiate) {
            echo '<hr>', PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
        }

        //Informa que encontrou ao menos um artigo
        $initiate = true;

        //Informa que estamos no titulo do artigo
        $inTitle = true;
        echo '<h1>', removeTags($buffer);
    } else if ($inTitle && $endLine) {
        //Se estiver no titulo e detectou um possivel fechamento do titulo
        $inTitle = false;
        echo removeTags($buffer), '</h1>', PHP_EOL;
    } else if ($initiate) {
        //Se não estiver dentro de um titulo ele imprime os dados
        $data = removeTags($buffer);

        //Se a linha for vazia então pula para a proxima linha
        if ($data === '') {
            continue;
        }

        echo $data, $inTitle ? '' : ('<br>' . PHP_EOL);
    }
}

//Fecha o arquivo temporario
fclose($temp);
```

Note que você pode trocar o `tmpfile` por `fopen` e salvar o HTML formatado para não precisar refazer a busca.

Este código é só um exemplo, por isto não fiz ele fazer tudo que é necessário, ainda é necessário mais alguns detalhes, mas o processo é o mesmo, basta você trabalhar usando as variaveis para detectar aonde começa e termina os itens do artigo por exemplo.

Comment: Boa tarde Guilherme, vi sim sua resposta, muito obrigado, estou estudando esse código que você enviou, tem muita coisa para aprender ainda, kkkk. 
O que você acha deste simplehtmldom - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/, acha que ajudaria?

E se puder me responder a outra pergunta, ficarei muito grato.
O porque o site oficial da constituição tem aquela formatação de html?

Valeu de novo, Guilherme

Comment: Então @AlêMoraes eu tentei este código, você pode até conseguir, mas como eu disse, é bastante trabalhoso, assim como o XPath. Ao menos pelo HTML que você está usando isto pode ser trabalhoso.

Comment: Guilherme, estou tentando entender o que você me enviou, mas, ainda é um pouco avançado para mim, mas estou estudando os comando deles, obrigado viu?

Eu pelo sublime text, consegui chegar rápido num resultado, e publiquei nesta pergunta, vê o achou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59374/atribuir-o-id-de-acordo-com-o-conte%C3%BAdo-do-texto

Comment: Boa noite Guilherme Nascimento, vê o que acha desta solução que encontrei.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59374/atribuir-o-id-de-acordo-com-o-conte%C3%BAdo-do-texto

Comment: @AlêMoraes Sinceramente amigo, eu acho muito trabalho atribuir IDs para algo que pode ser mais simples.

Comment: Mas, para se ter controle para cada artigo, não seria com ids?

Comment: @AlêMoraes mas com este seu exemplo quem atribui os IDs é "você", ou seja o seu código precisará atribuir IDs e depois captura-los e ainda sim você terá dificuldade em capturar os sub-topicos.

Comment: Guilherme, você está comentando da solução antiga (que é desta página), ou se da nova solução que é desta página http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59516/id-de-acordo-com-o-conte%C3%BAdo-da-string.

Concordo, que ainda o ID é só uma incrementação, estou estudando seu código, para implementa-lo, mas, no seu código, só a cabeça do artigo é envolvida numa h1, e o resto do artigo não fica dentro do artigo.

Eu sei que minha visão ainda sobre o código deve estar mais trabalhosa, mas, a estrutura era isso que imaginava, só o IDs de acordo com o paragrafo, o titulo, o capitulo, etc...