# Atribuir o id de acordo com o conteúdo do texto

Tags: php, javascript, sublime-text

Não sei se é melhor Javascript, PHP, ou ate mesmo o sublime text, mas,

Copiei [o texto da cf](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/constituicao/constituicaocompilado.htm) e colei num txt (para sumir as aquelas tags estranhas)

depois no sublime text, eu:

- selecionei tudo <kbd>crt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
- aperto <kbd>crt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> para fazer a inserção por linha
- aperto <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> para inserir tags de html em cada linha
- digito `li`, dai já cria as tags de abertura e fechamento para cada linha

Depois peço para selecionar todo:

```
</li>

<li>TÍTULO
```

e substituir por:

```
      </li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="titulo" class="titulo">
      <li>TÍTULO
```

E então, repeti esta fase para cada subseção: `titulo>capítulo>seção>subseção>artigo`

consegui chegar neste resultado: [cf_passo_1.txt](http://preliminarte.com.br/cf_passo_1.txt)

Gostaria de que o algoritmo pesquisasse cada `ul` e atribir o valor de `id` de acordo com o conteúdo de cada `ul`.

por exemplo, está assim:

```
<ul id="titulo" class="titulo">
   <li>
      TÍTULO I ...

<ul id="artigo" class="artigo">
   <li>
      Art.  1º A ...
```

gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
<ul id="titulo1" class="titulo">
   <li>
      TÍTULO I ...

<ul id="artigo1" class="artigo">
   <li>
      Art.  1º A ...
```

Comment: Só faltou o link do resultado
http://preliminarte.com.br/cf_passo_1.txt
Vlw

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você quer fazer um *parse* do texto e extrair alguma informação (tipo, o número do título, artigo, etc), possivelmente modificada (tipo, nºs romanos para arábicos). Certo? Se o conteúdo é estático - e você já está mesmo fazendo transformações "manuais" - sugiro experimentar primeiro com expressões regulares, talvez seja suficiente para o que você quer. Não conheço o sublime text, mas provavelmente deve ter essa opção no *find/replace*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o conteúdo me parece bem uniforme, um conjunto de substituições via expressões regulares deve ser suficiente para atingir seu objetivo. Essas substituições podem ser feitas de qualquer uma das três formas mencionadas: no próprio editor de texto (usando a função de "Pesquisar/Substituir" - *"Find/Replace"*) ou usando qualquer linguagem de programação, inclusive PHP e JavaScript. A sintaxe das *regexes* será semelhante em todos os casos ([PCRE](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)), a maneira de usá-las nem tanto.

A título de exemplo, a conversão dos artigos seria da seguinte forma:

Pesquisar:

```
<ul id="artigo" class="artigo">\n   <li>\n      Art\.  (\d)º
```

Substituir:

```
<ul id="artigo$1" class="artigo">\n   <li>\n      Art.  $1º
```

Os demais (que incluem números romanos) teriam a complicação adicional de convertê-los (se é que é mesmo importante convertê-los). Nessa hora ajuda o uso de uma linguagem de programação, onde você pode substituir o resultado do casamento pelo valor de retorno de uma função. Exemplo em JavaScript:

```
var regex = /<ul id="titulo" class="titulo">\n   <li>\n      TÍTULO ([^ ]+) /g
var convertido = str.replace(regex, function(match, romano) {
    var arabico = deromanize(romano);
    return '<ul id="titulo' + 
           arabico + 
           '" class="titulo">\n   <li>\n      TÍTULO ' + 
           romano + 
           ' ';
};
```

Usando uma função própria para converter romanos para arábicos, como [o `deromanize` descrito por esse artigo](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-roman-numeral-converter):

```
function deromanize (str) {
    var str = str.toUpperCase(),
        validator = /^M*(?:D?C{0,3}|C[MD])(?:L?X{0,3}|X[CL])(?:V?I{0,3}|I[XV])$/,
        token = /[MDLV]|C[MD]?|X[CL]?|I[XV]?/g,
        key = {M:1000,CM:900,D:500,CD:400,C:100,XC:90,L:50,XL:40,X:10,IX:9,V:5,IV:4,I:1},
        num = 0, m;
    if (!(str && validator.test(str)))
        return false;
    while (m = token.exec(str))
        num += key[m[0]];
    return num;
}
```